# Getting nothing returned when using msGraph to get a list of sites from an SPO tenant

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

I'm attempting to use msGraph to get a list of all hubsites, sites, subsites from my SharePoint Online tenant. Here is the code I'm using:

Package-solution:

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "User.ReadBasic.All"
      }
    ],
```

Data access:

```
export const GetSitesMsGraph = (context: any) => {
 return context.msGraphClientFactory
    .getClient('3')
    .then((client: MSGraphClientV3) => {
      client
        .api('sites')
        .version("v1.0")
        .get((err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
          }
          console.log(res)
          return res;
        })
    })
}
```

This returns an empty array.
I have tried swapping `.api('sites')` with `.api('/sites')` and still no return of data.

If I replace `.api('sites')` with `.api('users')` I get a full list of users from the tenant.
Is this `sites` incorrect?
I have made sure all SPFx calls that use msGraph have permission on the tenant admin.

I have read the below also:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by default the Graph API endpoint `/sites` returns empty value.

Workaround can be to use either `search` query parameter

```
.api('sites?search=')
.api('sites?search=*')
```

or with application permissions, you can list all sites

```
.api('sites/getAllSites')
```

What I remember even `/sites?search=*` doesn't return all subsites (across all geographies)

Comment: I don't get anything from ```search=*```, it returns an error saying it doesn't accept ```*```. It also says access denied when I use ```getAllSites```. How can I successfully get all users and not sites?

Comment: search should be without $, /sites endpoint is weird.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use ```.api('sites?search=WHAT HERE')``` please

Comment: Update: I got some sites back using ```.api('sites?search=*')```. But not all and it doesn't include subsites. Seems flaky to me.